# Use same variable in class /functions in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to use the same variable defined in a class and pass the same to function.
 For the below example I have used them separately.

I am new to Scala and learning class, objects and functions in scala .

```
class Mynewclass(var rcx: Int, var rcy: Int)  {
  var x = rcx
  var y = rcy

  def fn(fx: Int, fy: Int): Unit = {
    x = x + fx
    y = y + fy
    println(x,y)
  }
}

object ClassObject_learn {
  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val p1 = new Mynewclass(5,6)
    val p2 = new Mynewclass(6,7)
    new Mynewclass(5,6).fn(2,3)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @BalajiKrishnamoorthy, could you please be more clear about exactly what do you want to do?, I don't know which is the _variable_ you want to reuse.

Comment: I need to use only rcx , rcy through out class and in function too

Comment: So, you mean without creating `x` & `y`? - thus using `rcx` and `rcy` inside the body of your function?

Comment: Yes correct i need to use only rcx, rcy through out the body of class/function

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly. If you want to use rcx, rcy vars in method, why can't you simply do this?

```
class Mynewclass(var rcx:Int, var rcy:Int)  {
  def fn(fx:Int,  fy:Int) ={
    rcx = rcx + fx
    rcy = rcy + fy
    println(rcy,rcy)
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not possible to pass same or use same variables in function / class for any operation since iam in learning curve , please advise

Comment: @BalajiKrishnamoorthy, I understood exactly the same as Okrm, and I was going to post the same answer. But, I still can't understand exactly what you mean with "use same variable in function/class"?, Maybe you're concerned about the scope of a variable?

Comment: Yes i want to know if i can pass values from class to a function to perform an action .

Comment: class Mynewclass(var rcx:Int, var rcy:Int)  {
  def fn ()  =  (    rcx = rcx * 2 
   y = rcy + 2)
  }
}

Comment: @BalajiKrishnamoorthy Well if the function is inside the class, the function can use and modify _(please note that in functional programming languages, like scala, we prefer **immutability**)_ any variable/value that is in the scope of the class - and if the method is outside the class, you need an instance of the class and if the field is public you can use it too.

Comment: Thanks, what if i want to update particular instance  ?

Comment: Just pass the instance to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to modify a variable of a class in an external function.

```
class Point(var x: Int, var y: Int) {
  override def toString: String = s"($x, $y)"
}

object Main {
  def fn(point: Point, fx: Int, fy: Int): Unit = {
    point.x += fx
    point.y += fy
  }

  def main (args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val p1 = new Point(5,6)
    println(s"p1 = $p1")
    val p2 = new Point(6,7)
    println(s"p2 = $p2")
    fn(p1, 3, 5)
    println(s"p1 = $p1")
    println(s"p2 = $p2")
  }
}
```